# "Bending" a UIView in 3D

Tags: iphone, core-animation

What would be the best way of creating a CA animation that gives a sense of curvature to the view?

My initial approach is to create a grid of CALayers, each with a unique transformation matrix (I have some experience with OpenGL and this is how I would to this in GL). To do this I would need to divide the view in several quads (each represented by a CALayer). The question is, how can I do this. It would be allright to just take a snapshot of the view at animation start and use until the animation is complete (like transitions can do), but I am not sure how to take such a snapshot.

Any pointers (especially with links to code examples) would be of golden value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Classic answer:**

I think what you're probably looking for is CALayer's [renderInContext:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext:). Every UIView has a CALayer, which you can get via the [layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer) property. So you can build the CGContext you want (which will be a bitmap context, presumably), have the view's layer draw the view to the context, then do whatever you want with that data, whether it's divide it up into a bunch of UIImages and hence UIImageViews for a CoreAnimation effect, upload it to OpenGL or whatever.

Example code is provided directly by Apple in [Q&A 1703](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#qa/qa1703/_index.html), which uses the UIKit CoreGraphics extensions to jump straight to a UIImage and digs through all the available windows to capture an image of the entire screen. But it shows you the essence of the thing.

---

**Updated in 2015:**

As of iOS 7, as documented in [Q&A 1817](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014134), `UIView` provides `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` which reduces the code necessary to snapshot a view even further — to four lines in Apple's example code. It appears Q&A 1703 has been withdrawn as it is no longer available on Apple's side; the link above is to an external archived copy. So the 1817 advice is the stuff to follow.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Remember reading about it a long while ago, but didn't remember the relevant keywords to search for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Q&A link is broken.

Comment: That appears to be because iOS 7 introduced an even easier method as per QA1817 — https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014134 ; I need to dash into a meeting now but will try to update my answer later.